Python CDLL cannot be loaded twice
I am trying to make a password manager in python and have ran into a issue: I cannot load a different dll once I have loaded one type of dll. In this example I have loaded a dll and am trying to decrypt encrypted password data and it works fine until I load another DIFFERENT nss3.dll file at which point it gives me an error:

The procedure entry point HeapAlloc could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\Program Files\Waterfox\nss3.dll

I only get this error after loading multiple nss3.dll files for example:
def DecryptFirefoxBased(Type,EncryptedPassword):
    EncryptedPassword = base64.b64decode(EncryptedPassword)
    nss3 = ctypes.CDLL(Paths[Type][1])
    nss_init = nss3.NSS_Init
    nss_init.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p]
    nss_init.restype = ctypes.c_int
    nss_init(ProfileDirectory.encode())
    pk11_sdr_decrypt = nss3.PK11SDR_Decrypt
    pk11_sdr_decrypt.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(SecItem), ctypes.POINTER(SecItem), ctypes.c_int]
    pk11_sdr_decrypt.restype = ctypes.c_int
    EncryptedItem = SecItem()
    EncryptedItem.data = ctypes.create_string_buffer(EncryptedPassword)
    EncryptedItem.len = len(EncryptedPassword)
    DecryptedItem = SecItem()
    decrypted_buffer = ctypes.create_string_buffer(len(EncryptedPassword))
    DecryptedItem.data = ctypes.cast(decrypted_buffer, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char))
    DecryptedItem.len = len(EncryptedPassword)
    ret = pk11_sdr_decrypt(ctypes.byref(EncryptedItem), ctypes.byref(DecryptedItem), 0)
    if ret != 0:
        input("PK11SDR_Decrypt failed")
    return ctypes.string_at(DecryptedItem.data, DecryptedItem.len).decode()

Paths[Type][1] = "C:\Users\me\Program Files\nss3.dll"
In the reference above that is being called more than once with a different dll being loaded each time, on the second different nss3.dll lib it breaks. How can I fix this?

I am also making a sort of password manager, but I modelled it directly on passwd. The hashlib standard module will be useful for you.
